# activate different media query although screen resolution does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I'm in the following situation:

I have media-query A for screenresolution: width<1200px.

I have media-query B for screenresolution: width>1200px.

There is a Button in the document with a click eventhandler.
Currently my screenresolution is below 1200px, so Elements use media-query A.
Inside this eventhandler I'd like to force my Elements to use media-query B.
Is this possible?

I know how to manipulate the dom with JS, but that's what I want to avoid here.
Is there a solution for this?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Do you want to force all Elements to use media-query B inside Click eventhandler ?

Comment: yes, everything declared in media-query B should be assigned to the elements mentioned in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a simple way, in your `click` handler, if you try to add a class to the `<body>` tag and add all the B media query's CSS inside the new class and target all the required selectors, your work is done.

Resolution: < 1200 px:

- Body uses `A` media query.
- Body with `.fake-b-class` class uses `B` media query.

Hope this helps you. In simple words, you copy all the styles in `B` media query to `A.fake-b-class`.

Consider the `@media` query example here:

```
/* This is B style! */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

/* This is A style */
body.fake-b-class {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Hope you get it better.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly. How could the css-file look like? I'm not only trying to give the body a diffrent css, I want to change over 30 Elements inside the body.

Comment: @ant45de Not the CSS file but the selectors. Lemme update my answer with an example.

Comment: That would be nice of you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! As far as I understand, your solution requires that every element needs its own fake-class to switch styles. I mean A is not a media-query and speaks to a single Element. My media-query A contains 5 css-rules, B contains also 5 css-rules. Can I switch between media-queries without having a fake-class for every element?

Comment: @ant45de If you use SASS, it is easy to automate. Just `@include`. :D

Comment: I just had look at SASS and especially at @include and I don't understand how this is easy ;( How can I switch between the includes? Do you know a tutorial or something where this is shown?

Comment: @ant45de Did you understand or still need help?

Comment: Yes I understood how SASS works but I dont have 2 media-queries as I mentioned in my question but 12. So SASS is an alternative for a small amount, but not for me. I already found a solution by seperating them in css-files and loading them dynamically, but thanks a lot for your effort :)